# Using" whose" in relative clauses

Tags: grammar

When do we use "whose " in a relative clause?
People, things, or places? 
Thanks for advanced!

Comment: You use _whose_ when it is necessary to have the relative pronoun be possessive. Non-possessive relative pronouns are _who_ for people, _which_ for things, and _that_ for either people or things. _That_ has no possessive, and neither does _which_, but _who_ has a possessive for _whose_, which/that can be used for **anything** - person, thing, concept, whatever -  as long as it's possessing something. Ex: _The man whose mother arrived greeted her. The box whose cover was stuck contained glue. I read the paper whose author didn't attend the conference._

Comment: Ohhh I got it. Do amazing! Thank you!